# Zbook with Kubuntu is running hot

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, hp, temperature

I have here a "HP ZBook Firefly 15 inch G8 Mobile Workstation PC" running "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" in the Kubuntu variant. Since some days, probably after the last kernel update, the computer gets very hot and the fan is running constantly at max. Even when there is a low load on the system, even before login in as user. There is no program running using a high percentage of CPU or memory.

I did try running a Kubuntu live USB stick and there this did not happen. I also tried running it with the oldest still installed kernel and here it also runs hot.

Since way longer that the temperature issue exists, there is a "HP System Firmware" update shown in the "Update - Discover" tool which immediately disappears when I start the update and shows up the next time again. Maybe this issues are connected.

What can cause that and how to resolve it? Thank you for any insights!

System info (old kernel):

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-46-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 31.0 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Kubuntu 23.04 seams to have removed this issue. (Actually already the intermediate update to 22.10).